# R CMD BATCH without echo

Tags: r

I'm running an R script in batch mode on Linux and want to suppress any echo/message from R.

I've tried `R CMD BATCH --slave --no-timing` with and without `options( echo = FALSE )`. I did get the timing snippet to go away, but can't suppress the echo of packages loading. I'd like to keep the output of `print` only.

What options should I use to suppress all echo/R messages? Thanks.

Script `test.R` :

```
 options(echo=FALSE)
 require(RMySQL)
 print(runif(10))
```

Result:

```
 $ R CMD BATCH --slave --no-timing test.R res
 $ head res
 Loading required package: RMySQL
 Loading required package: DBI
  [1] 0.6520674 0.8649830 0.4784035 0.8932107 0.4949176 0.5245653 0.1879956
  [8] 0.4875924 0.3212427 0.6686655
```

Comment: Is it the "Loading required..." messages you want gone or do you want the printed output gone as well?

Comment: Yes. I'd like to have the output of `print` only. I've tried `library(RMySQL)` and get R's feedback on those calls too.

Comment: Check out `?suppressPackageStartupMessages`

Comment: OK, thanks. That doc is really on the opaque side. I think I'll run the R output thru `sed`.

Comment: Just wrap `require(package)` in that function.  In other words `suppressPackageStartupMessages(require(package))` will do what you want.

Comment: OK, that did the trick. I'd be glad to upvote the answer if you want to post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wrap `require(package)` with `suppressPackageStartupMessages`. In other words `suppressPackageStartupMessages(require(package))` will do what you want.

```
suppressPackageStartupMessages(require(RMySQL))
print(runif(10))
```